# Using external URL in Play framework script tag

Tags: playframework-2.0

How can I refer to external urls from the script tag in my view? I have a view html file in my Play framework project and I want to refer to some external urls for the javascript part. Here is what I have!

```
  <div id=”twitter_update_list”>
        <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js”></script>
        <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/xxxxxx.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1″></script>
    </div>
```

This fails when it is rendered in the browser. How to refer to external sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Play Framework script tag, that's just a straight HTML script tag.

Anyway, if you have copied the code as is, then the problem is your double quotes, they are unicode right double quotes, ”, see how they are slanted to the right? That's not valid HTML.  Replace them with ASCII double quotes: ".  Just to emphasise the difference, here they are side by side: ” "

If that's not the problem, then describe what you mean by "fails".  Are there any error messages displayed?  What is shown in the developer console?  Can you see the script being downloaded in the Network tab of the developer console?